# Problem with navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, amcl, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am new to ROS, so please bear with me.
I am going through navigation tutorials of ROS listed [here](http://wiki.ros.org/husky_navigation/Tutorials/Husky%20AMCL%20Demo).

When I launch the amcl.demo file I get the following error continuously:

**[WARN] [1454762481.036046933, 3051.340000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.**

Due to this, the 2D pose Estimate and 2D nav goal don't work in Rviz. The Exploration, Static map, Global Costmap, Local Costmap show an error in Rviz.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks!

EDIT 1: Here is the summary of the terminal:

```
sri@Sri:~$ roslaunch husky_navigation amcl_demo.launch
... logging to /home/sri/.ros/log/99bc8912-cd81-11e5-9cc6-681729436688/roslaunch-Sri-16730.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://Sri:40227/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /amcl/gui_publish_rate: 10.0
 * /amcl/kld_err: 0.05
 * /amcl/kld_z: 0.99
 * /amcl/laser_lambda_short: 0.1
 * /amcl/laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
 * /amcl/laser_max_beams: 60
 * /amcl/laser_max_range: 12.0
 * /amcl/laser_model_type: likelihood_field
 * /amcl/laser_sigma_hit: 0.2
 * /amcl/laser_z_hit: 0.5
 * /amcl/laser_z_max: 0.05
 * /amcl/laser_z_rand: 0.5
 * /amcl/laser_z_short: 0.05
 * /amcl/max_particles: 2000
 * /amcl/min_particles: 500
 * /amcl/odom_alpha1: 0.2
 * /amcl/odom_alpha2: 0.2
 * /amcl/odom_alpha3: 0.2
 * /amcl/odom_alpha4: 0.2
 * /amcl/odom_alpha5: 0.1
 * /amcl/odom_frame_id: odom
 * /amcl/odom_model_type: diff
 * /amcl/recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
 * /amcl/recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
 * /amcl/resample_interval: 1
 * /amcl/transform_tolerance: 1.0
 * /amcl/update_min_a: 0.2
 * /amcl/update_min_d: 0.25
 * /amcl/use_map_topic: True
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_th: 3.2
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_x: 2.5
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_y: 0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/latch_xy_goal_tolerance: False
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_rot_vel: 1.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_trans_vel: 0.5
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_x: 0.5
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_y: 0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_rot_vel: 0.2
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_trans_vel: 0.1
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_x: 0.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_y: 0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
 * /move_base/NavfnROS/allow_unknown: True
 * /move_base/NavfnROS/default_tolerance: 0.1
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_theta: 3.2
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_x: 2.5
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/angular_sim_granularity: 0.02
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/controller_frequency: 20.0
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/dwa: True
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/escape_reset_dist: 0.1
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/escape_reset_theta: 0.1
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/escape_vel: -0.1
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/gdist_scale: 1.0
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_lookahead: 0.325
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_scoring: False
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_scoring_timestep: 0.8
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/holonomic_robot: False
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/latch_xy_goal_tolerance: False
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_theta: 1.0
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_x: 1.0
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/meter_scoring: True
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.2
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_theta: -1.0
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_x: 0.0
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/occdist_scale: 0.1
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/oscillation_reset_dist: 0.25
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/pdist_scale: 0.75
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/publish_cost_grid_pc: True
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_granularity: 0.02
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_time: 2.0
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/simple_attractor: False
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/vtheta_samples: 20
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/vx_samples: 6
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
 * /move_base/base_global_planner: navfn/NavfnROS
 * /move_base/base_local_planner: dwa_local_planner...
 * /move_base/controller_frequency: 5.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint: [[-0.5, -0.33], [...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint_padding: 0.01
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_frame: map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation/inflation_radius: 1.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_range: 5.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacles_laser/laser/clearing: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacles_laser/laser/data_type: LaserScan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacles_laser/laser/inf_is_valid: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacles_laser/laser/marking: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacles_laser/laser/topic: scan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacles_laser/observation_sources: laser
 * /move_base/global_costmap/plugins: [{'type': 'costma...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/publish_frequency: 3.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/raytrace_range: 6.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/resolution: 0.05
 * /move_base/global_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/global_costmap/rolling_window: False
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static/map_topic: /map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static/subscribe_to_updates: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/track_unknown_space: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/update_frequency: 4.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint: [[-0.5, -0.33], [...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint_padding: 0.01
 * /move_base/local_costmap/global_frame: odom
 * /move_base/local_costmap/height: 10.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation/inflation_radius: 1.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_range: 5.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles_laser/laser/clearing: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles_laser/laser/data_type: LaserScan
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles_laser/laser/inf_is_valid: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles_laser/laser/marking: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles_laser/laser/topic: scan
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles_laser/observation_sources: laser
 * /move_base/local_costmap/plugins: [{'type': 'costma...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/publish_frequency: 3.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/raytrace_range: 6.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/resolution: 0.05
 * /move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/local_costmap/rolling_window: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static/map_topic: /map
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static/subscribe_to_updates: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/update_frequency: 4.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/width: 10.0
 * /move_base/recovery_behaviour_enabled: True
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.16

NODES
  /
    amcl (amcl/amcl)
    map_server (map_server/map_server)
    move_base (move_base/move_base)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[map_server-1]: started with pid [16748]
process[amcl-2]: started with pid [16749]
process[move_base-3]: started with pid [16755]
[ WARN] [1454839265.612888152, 1338.590000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225977/problem-with-navigation/) by [Srinidhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25631/srinidhi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-02-07**:
Error missing

**Comment by [Srinidhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25631/srinidhi/) on 2016-02-07**:
Sorry. I have added the error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to replicate this error, and got rid of it by running sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-husky-*

This installed a few additional husky packages that I didn't have, and then it all worked fine

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Srinidhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25631/srinidhi/) on 2016-02-08**:
Thank you so much! This worked like a charm.

Also, it should be ros instead of rose in the answer. Please rectify it. Thanks!

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-02-08**:
well spotted - the perils of auto correct